# OpenDaylight: How to get notified when a switch connects

Tags: opendaylight

I am working with opendaylight Carbon. I want to write a DataTreeChangeListener which gets notified when a switch connects. I tried modeling this on the LearningSwitch example of the OpenFlow plugin but I do not see any notification when mininet connects to openflow.

Any pointers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is is OK for you if you get notified when a link appears (and therefore, get the source and destination switches from the link)?

Comment: I found a good pointer on how to do this by looking at the learningswitch example. However, I now find I get multiple notifications.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by multiple notifications? Or show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [this](https://github.com/opendaylight/netvirt/blob/master/vpnservice/vpnmanager/vpnmanager-impl/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/netvirt/vpnmanager/VpnNodeListener.java), we use this class to add default flows when DPN gets connected